# GitLab in Docker fails on chgrp

Tags: docker, gitlab, raspberry-pi4, raspberry-os

I have just ventured into the world of Docker on my RPI4 running the 64-bit version of Raspberry OS. I have tried to setup GitLab using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/ravermeister/gitlab) docker image. I have made a CIFS mount to my NAS box

```
//NAS-IP/gitlab  /mnt/gitlab  cifs  username=xxx,password=xxx,iocharset=utf8,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777  0  0
```

which I use as storage volume provided to the GitLab container which I have setup using the following:

```
docker run -d \
-p 4443:443 -p 8080:80 -p 2222:22 \
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
-v /home/pi/GitLab/config:/etc/gitlab \
-v /home/pi/GitLab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
-v /mnt/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
ravermeister/gitlab
```

I'm not sure if I should point all three volumes to my NAS box or just the data volume (as I have done here)?

According to my Portainer site on the RPI4 the GitLab container is healthy/starting/running, but the RPI4 keeps running the same GitLab processes again and again and in the pile of GitLab log files (`/home/pi/GitLab/logs/reconfigure`), I can see that something in the container fails:

```
[2021-03-02T20:03:47+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2021-03-02T20:03:47+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2021-03-02T20:03:47+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2021-03-02T20:03:47+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2021-03-02T20:03:47+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (gitlab::gitlab-shell line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/storage_directory.rb line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: chgrp: changing group of '/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh': Operation not permitted
---- End output of chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
Ran chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh returned 1
```

The GitLab container has written stuff to both the config, log and data volume so it has write permissions.

Is this something which can be fixed using my relatively limited linux skills and what can I try to do?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab is trying to change the group ownership of the .ssh folder.

The container already has warning about the ACL and group rights in it's [manifest](https://hub.docker.com/r/ravermeister/gitlab) on GitHub:

> "If you are using file ACLs on the docker host, the docker[^1] group requires full access to the volumes in order for GitLab to work. ..."

So start by checking this.

If you are not able to clear the mounted folder `/mnt/gitlab/data` on your host (which is the folder that should hold the `.ssh` which the container is trying to change, next in line is to check what is the current group of the `.ssh` on the host and what is the expected to be in the container and than try to change it outside the container. Based on the ACL file I expect to be the group `docker`.