# How to deploy container Gitlab on a mounted point?

Tags: docker, gitlab, nas

I'm trying to mount one container Gitlab on my CIFS mounted point, but that returns errors.

I have my Nas CIFS mounted point at `/mnt/serveurwiki/` and i have 2 folders in "gitlab" and "wiki".

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I have all rights on the folder.

And this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'
services:

  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    user: root
    ports:
      - '42007:80'
      - '42008:443'
      - '42009:22'

    volumes:
      - /mnt/serveurwiki/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - /mnt/serveurwiki/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /mnt/serveurwiki/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab

    networks:
      - network

networks:
  network:
```

For precision, I tested the compose in other positions and all work, but when I try to deploy my container in my point mount (`/mnt/serveurwiki`), I have that error in the logs of the container.

```
[2022-07-11T08:56:12+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2022-07-11T08:56:12+00:00] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-07-11T08:56:12+00:00] FATAL: PLEASE PROVIDE THE CONTENTS OF THE stacktrace.out FILE (above) IF YOU FILE A BUG REPORT
[2022-07-11T08:56:12+00:00] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-07-11T08:56:12+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (gitlab::gitlab-shell line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (gitlab::gitlab-shell line 36) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: chgrp: changing group of '/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh': Operation not permitted
---- End output of chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
Ran chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh returned 1
```

Anyone have an idea what I can do for that and why I have that error?

Comment: Similar issue here, looks like you need to grant full access to the docker group for all mounted folders https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446475/gitlab-in-docker-fails-on-chgrp

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer but i check my ACL on the CIFS mounted point, and that seem good. Anyway i can't modify ACL on a CIFS volume. (or i don't know how do that)
# file: mnt/serveurwiki/
# owner: root
# group: docker
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

Comment: for precision, my mouting volume (/mnt/serveurwiki) is format in BTRFS

Answer (score 0):

For testing, you could:

- build your own image based on `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`
- change the `ENTRYPOINT` to call your own script before calling the one from GitLab
- [check/change the permissions of `/var/opt/gitlab`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72797313/6309) in your custom `ENTRYPOINT` script.

That way, you have a better control of the environment used by the GitLab image.